# Autocomplete prefix command in bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have to launch my applications using a number of prefix commands (like `xvbf-run`). The launch scripts/applications have a functioning autocomplete. So the following works `script1 <TAB><TAB>`.

But the following fails to work correctly `{prefix with options} script1 <TAB><TAB>` (obviously). Since the options are fixed, I created a simple function:

```
function prefix_summary () {
    {prefix with options} $@ 
}
```

I tried `complete -F _longopt prefix_summary` but that doesn't work. How can I allow `prefix_summary` to act like a bash prompt?

**TLDR**: make this `$ prefix_summary <TAB><TAB>` give same autocomplete options as this `$ <TAB><TAB>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want a `sudo`-like completion.

Let's look at how completion is defined for `sudo`:

```
$ complete -p sudo
complete -F _sudo sudo
```

Then, you only need to apply the same completion rules (defined in the function `_sudo()`) to your prefixes.

```
$ complete -F _sudo prefix1 prefix2
```

Now, hitting <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> after `$ prefix1` and `$ prefix2` will autocomplete with commands from paths in `$PATH`.

Hitting <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> after `$ prefix1 cmd1` will autocomplete with suggestions from `cmd1` completion rules.